# ASP.NET MVC (4) - Bind properties in a certain order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to force binding of properties A and B before C?

There's Order property in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute class, but does it affect binding order?

What i'm trying to achieve is

```
page.Path = page.Parent.Path + "/" + page.Slug
```

in a custom ModelBinder

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that `page.Parent.Path` and `page.Slug` are being bound to from the form and that you want `page.Path` to be set to the concatenation of their contents just after binding occurs?  i.e. the `page.Path` value does not exist on the form?

Comment: @Dangerous correct, `page.Path` is not on the form. I get `page.Parent.Id` and `page.Slug` from the form.

Comment: And I want to build the `page.Path` after the `page.Parent` and `page.Slug` are bound.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Order property is used when using Html helper methods like EditorForModel or DisplayForModel an an entire model http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayformodel.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have initially recommended Sams answer as it would have not involved any binding of the Path property at all.  You mentioned that you could concatenate the values using a Path property as this would cause lazy loading to occur.  I imagine therefore you are using your domain models to display information to the view. I would therefore recommend using view models to display only the information required in the view (then use Sams answer to retrieve the path) and then map the view model to the domain model using a tool (i.e. [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)).

However, if you continue to use your existing model in the view and you cannot use the other values in the model, you can set the path property to the values provided by the form value provider in a custom model binder after the other binding has occurred (assuming no validation is to be performed on the path property).

So lets assume you have the following view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Parent Path: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ParentPath)</p>
    <p>Slug: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Slug)</p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

And the following view model (or domain model as the case may be):

public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string ParentPath { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

You can then specify the following model binder:

```
public class IndexViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            //Note: Model binding of the other values will have already occurred when this method is called.

            string parentPath = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ParentPath").AttemptedValue;
            string slug = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Slug").AttemptedValue;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentPath) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(slug))
            {
                IndexViewModel model = (IndexViewModel)bindingContext.Model;
                model.Path = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ParentPath").AttemptedValue + "/" + bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Slug").AttemptedValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally specify that this model binder is to be used by using the following attribute on the view model:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(IndexViewModelBinder))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement the Page property as:

```
public string Path{
    get { return string.Format("{0}/{1}", Parent.Path, Slug); }
}
```

?

Comment: That would cause lazy loading of all page's ancestors one by one. Eg. if you display 10 pages (each at level 3 in the hierarchy) that could cause extra 20 queries to the database.